# Missing GLIBCXX_3.4.14 etc. for FoxitReader

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, libraries

I'm on CentOS 6.9 32-bit architecture and I'm trying to install FoxitReader, a PDF viewer that also lets you annotate existing pdfs.

As per official instructions found on the application's website, FoxitReader got installed in `/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/` but when I try to launch it as root user I get:

```
[dolly@centos opt]$ sudo FoxitReader 
/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.14' not found (required by /opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader)
/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader)
/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader)
/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader: /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.15' not found (required by /opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/lib/libQt5WebKit.so.5)
/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.15' not found (required by /opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0)
/opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/FoxitReader: /lib/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.17' not found (required by /opt/foxitsoftware/foxitreader/lib/libgstreamer-0.10.so.0)
[dolly@centos opt]$
```

Taking the cue from similar threads on Stackoverflow, I tried:

```
[dolly@centos opt]$ strings /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIB
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBC_2.0
GLIBC_2.3
GLIBC_2.4
GLIBC_2.1
GLIBC_2.1.3
GLIBC_2.3.2
GLIBC_2.2
GLIBCXX_FORCE_NEW
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
[dolly@centos opt]$
```

People were talking about creating soft-links to the appropriate libraries but I don't think this is my case, isn't it? 
Furthermore:

```
[dolly@centos opt]$ rpm -q glibc
glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686
[dolly@centos opt]$ rpm -qa | grep glibc
glibc-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686
glibc-headers-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686
glibc-common-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686
glibc-devel-2.12-1.209.el6_9.2.i686
[dolly@centos opt]$
```

Any ideas how I can get FoxitReader to launch from CLI (or via GUI, neither are working...)?

Comment: The short answer: you can't. Foxit requires a C++ ABI that is not supported by your libstdc++.

Comment: No way I can install the missing libraries from somewhere? Maybe patch things up?

Comment: You're talking about the C++ runtime library. Arguably the most complicated general purpose programming language in use today. And, the C++ ABI that this application needs is, apparently, newer than the one your Linux distro comes with. Perhaps you would've had a snowball's chance in hell if you needed compatibility with an older ABI. But with a newer ABI, the only realistic approach is to upgrade yourself to a newer Linux distro that supports the required ABI level; most likely CentOS 7.